# Does this poetic device have a name

Tags: ambiguity, poetry, syntactic-analysis, poetic-devices

Consider this couplet (it's just an example)

> The driver drove home safely.
>   The Traveller returned home.
>
> The driver drove home. Safely,
>   the Traveller returned home.

If the placement of the period is not explicit then it is ambiguous (assume no capitalization and no punctuation). But both versions make sense (sort of, it's not a great eg)

Is this a poetic device? Does it have a name?

Comment: Welcome! How would it look if the period was not explicit? Would "safely" have a capital "S"? Would the comma be there?

Comment: No and no. Basically anything that could give one of the parses priority over the other is not there. Ie. both the sentences are the intended meaning

Comment: It seems like it is a kind of *double entendre*.

Comment: *Is this a poetic device? Does it have a name?* It's called *poetry*; very many poems are deliberately written to offer the reader multiple interpretations (or parses) and unresolved ambiguities, offering a richness of meaning beyond what the same words, in clearly punctuated prose, would provide.

Comment: It's known as *amphiboly* or [*syntactic ambiguity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was looking for